# Filter Log By Event Id (or by LogMessage)

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core

In nLog I am able to setup (in nlog.config or via Code) some so called `ConditionBasedFilters` like:

```
<filters defaultAction='Log'>
        <when condition="equals('${event-context:item=EventId}','Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation.DecimalTypeKeyWarning')" action="Ignore" />
</filters>
```

With this I can filter log messages based on the actual `LogMessage` or `EventId` etc. (see
Official nLog doku: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#example-in-c )

---

Is there some similar feature in asp.net core Logging? (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#how-filtering-rules-are-applied )

As far as I can see it only supports filtering on `LogLevel`, `Category` and `Provider` but not on for instance the actual `LogMessage` or `EventId` - Is there some feature, that I am missing?

Comment: As per the [tagging help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), please don't put tags in your question titles. I've removed the tag from your title for you.

Comment: @Llama thx! I am sorry, I did not know that yet. Also while searching through stackoverflow I regularly saw ".net CORE" questions. sorry for the problems might caused by this

Comment: No worries. I just like to comment so that people know that removing it wasn't malicious, and so that they know about the guidelines.  :)